# Publishing a game on Steam. Who's name to put in dev info, do I need a company?

Tags: steam, publishing

I'm currently paying a game dev to create me a game that I can publish on Steam.

Should I put the devs name or mine for the dev info on Steam?

Do I need a legitimate company in the UK to sell a game on Steam?

Comment: Please keep in mind that besides publishing on Steam, there are other aspects of UK company law which might be relevant for you and might mean that you need to form a company. We can help you with the process of publishing on Steam, but [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com) might be better equipped to handle all the other aspects of UK company law.

Comment: This is off-topic question for this site. Legal questions should be asked at [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) as @Philipp already commented. We here are not really in any position to give any kind of help with law matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are separate fields for publisher and developer on Steam, so I would advice that you put the actual developer's name in the developer field and your name in the publisher field. However, if you have a deal with the developer that they give full rights to the game to you and are not supposed to have their name anywhere after that, obviously do not put their name on Steam.

IANAL, but as far as I know, you do not *need* to have a legal company setup, you *can* publish as an individual. Whether or not you want to do that is for you to decide. A company can protect you from financial liabilities for an example.